# CI: Argument Count Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a project & I've encounter with this problem "**Argument Count Error**". I've checked code by code but did not find anything.

Controller Code:

```
public function new_package(){
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $price = $this->input->post('price');
    $description = $this->input->post('description');

    if($name != '' && $price != '' && $description != ''){
        $packageData = $this->Process->package_add($name, $price, $description);

        if($packageData){
            $added = "Package Added";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('added', $added);
            redirect('Packages');
        }
    }
    else{
        $blank = "Please Fill Required Fields.";
        $this->session->set_flashdata('blank', $blank);
        redirect('Packages');
    }
}
```

Modal Code:

```
public function package_add($name, $price, $description){
    $insertData = array(
        'title' => $name,
        'price' => $price,
        'description' => $description
    );

    $insertQuery = $this->db->insert('packages', $insertData);

    if($insertQuery){
        return TRUE;
    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Modal name **Process**.

> Error: ""Type: ArgumentCountError
>
> Message: Too few arguments to function Process::package_add(), 0
>   passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\apn_new\backend\application\controllers\Packages.php
>   on line 32 and exactly 3 expected
>
> Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\apn_new\backend\application\models\Process.php
>
> Line Number: 299""

I've search over this site related this type problem but I did not find my problem solution. This problem comes before submit form. Please Help me.

Thank You

Comment: $this->Process->package_add($name, $price, $description); try $this->Process->package_add('test','100','test D'); pass this and check result. even if this fails then check Model function.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy getting same error.

Comment: is your model loading correctly. Modal name must be Name_modal.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy yes model load perfectly. Other codes working perfectly. Add, Update, Delete all codes working fine. I copied those code and changes variables and function name but getting same result.

Comment: Another call to package_add() may be existing somewhere.

Comment: @Mr.Blue no i can't post. when i click package menu i show this error. no matter what i try error stays. I changed function name with my name but same result.

Comment: Thank Everyone, problem solve. I've re-wright my code and it run.

Comment: @MarufAhmed you got know the problem?

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy yes, I got the problem. I call that function twice same controller, that was the problem. after removing code run again.

Comment: you should close this question as its unlikely to help others

Answer (score 1):

Create insert array in controller

Controller.php

```
public function new_package(){
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $price = $this->input->post('price');
    $description = $this->input->post('description');

    if($name != '' && $price != '' && $description != ''){
        $insertData = array(
        'title' => $name,
        'price' => $price,
        'description' => $description
        );
        $packageData = $this->Process->package_add($insertData);

        if($packageData){
            $added = "Package Added";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('added', $added);
            redirect('Packages');
        }
    }
    else{
        $blank = "Please Fill Required Fields.";
        $this->session->set_flashdata('blank', $blank);
        redirect('Packages');
    }
}
```

Model.php

```
public function package_add($insertData){

    $insertQuery = $this->db->insert('packages', $insertData);

    if($insertQuery){
        return TRUE;
    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```